# Plotting means of groupby's with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I've just discovered how powerful seaborn is, so I'm just wondering whether it's capable of achieving something like this (see below) with a simple command.

Let's say I have this type of DataFrame:

```
   cond  var0_0      var0_1      var0_2      var1_0      var1_1      var1_2      var2_0      var2_1     var2_2

0   0   0.302645    0.018080    0.490951    0.372200    0.540828    0.209754    0.600751    0.431513    0.480047
1   1   0.769827    0.444092    0.889245    0.478391    0.710957    0.559171    0.047525    0.892624    0.491747
2   2   0.464153    0.911308    0.380770    0.258177    0.536402    0.411656    0.689097    0.685418    0.704515
3   0   0.534112    0.368735    0.537422    0.696765    0.079819    0.631238    0.319000    0.073374    0.454915
4   1   0.664653    0.842020    0.076439    0.841436    0.896321    0.689220    0.453462    0.326244    0.448504
5   2   0.811572    0.915799    0.556698    0.391307    0.058318    0.029848    0.043365    0.403045    0.184536
6   0   0.285779    0.817161    0.795836    0.137391    0.494213    0.059073    0.218697    0.480208    0.215314
7   1   0.346941    0.207986    0.413195    0.593996    0.223914    0.465081    0.746621    0.057151    0.184877
8   2   0.079715    0.670232    0.425488    0.479693    0.471829    0.747377    0.731847    0.070246    0.923183
```

and for each `cond` groupby, I would like to build three different profiles of the type (`mean(vari_0), mean(vari_1), mean(vari_2)`) where `i` covers all variables in the dataframe (i.e. it goes from 0 to 2).

Of course if I was to proceed with straightforward python I'd start with:

```
df.groupby(['cond']).mean()

cond    var0_0      var0_1      var0_2      var1_0      var1_1      var1_2      var2_0      var2_1   var2_2                                 
0       0.374179    0.401325    0.608069    0.402119    0.371620    0.300022    0.379482    0.328365    0.383425
1       0.593807    0.498033    0.459627    0.637941    0.610398    0.571158    0.415869    0.425340    0.375043
2       0.451814    0.832446    0.454319    0.376393    0.355516    0.396294    0.488103    0.386236    0.604078
```

then take each row, split it in three parts, etc...

The goal is to plot something like this (plot filled with random values):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a `pandas` question really, since the issue is how to transform your dataframe in a format that is suitable for seaborn.

I think what you are trying to do is doable, but it takes a few steps.

Starting with your original dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
   cond  var0_0      var0_1      var0_2      var1_0      var1_1      var1_2      var2_0      var2_1     var2_2

0   0   0.302645    0.018080    0.490951    0.372200    0.540828    0.209754    0.600751    0.431513    0.480047
1   1   0.769827    0.444092    0.889245    0.478391    0.710957    0.559171    0.047525    0.892624    0.491747
2   2   0.464153    0.911308    0.380770    0.258177    0.536402    0.411656    0.689097    0.685418    0.704515
3   0   0.534112    0.368735    0.537422    0.696765    0.079819    0.631238    0.319000    0.073374    0.454915
4   1   0.664653    0.842020    0.076439    0.841436    0.896321    0.689220    0.453462    0.326244    0.448504
5   2   0.811572    0.915799    0.556698    0.391307    0.058318    0.029848    0.043365    0.403045    0.184536
6   0   0.285779    0.817161    0.795836    0.137391    0.494213    0.059073    0.218697    0.480208    0.215314
7   1   0.346941    0.207986    0.413195    0.593996    0.223914    0.465081    0.746621    0.057151    0.184877
8   2   0.079715    0.670232    0.425488    0.479693    0.471829    0.747377    0.731847    0.070246    0.923183'''),
                sep='\\s+', header=0, index_col=0)
```

Start, as you did by taking the average per condition

```
df2 = df.groupby(['cond']).mean().reset_index()
```

```
   cond    var0_0    var0_1    var0_2    var1_0    var1_1    var1_2    var2_0    var2_1    var2_2
0     0  0.374179  0.401325  0.608070  0.402119  0.371620  0.300022  0.379483  0.328365  0.383425
1     1  0.593807  0.498033  0.459626  0.637941  0.610397  0.571157  0.415869  0.425340  0.375043
2     2  0.451813  0.832446  0.454319  0.376392  0.355516  0.396294  0.488103  0.386236  0.604078'
```

You can then combine each of your three `varX` columns using [`pd.wide_to_long()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
df3 = pd.wide_to_long(df2, stubnames=[f'var{i:d}' for i in range(3)], i=['cond'], j='y', sep='_', suffix='\d')
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

```
   cond  y      var0      var1      var2
0     0  0  0.374179  0.402119  0.379483
1     1  0  0.593807  0.637941  0.415869
2     2  0  0.451813  0.376392  0.488103
3     0  1  0.401325  0.371620  0.328365
4     1  1  0.498033  0.610397  0.425340
5     2  1  0.832446  0.355516  0.386236
6     0  2  0.608070  0.300022  0.383425
7     1  2  0.459626  0.571157  0.375043
8     2  2  0.454319  0.396294  0.604078
```

Finally, `seaborn` wants a long for dataframe, so you need to melt to have all your values in a single column:

```
df4 = df3.melt(id_vars=['cond','y'])
```

```
'    cond  y variable     value
0      0  0     var0  0.374179
1      1  0     var0  0.593807
2      2  0     var0  0.451813
3      0  1     var0  0.401325
4      1  1     var0  0.498033
5      2  1     var0  0.832446
6      0  2     var0  0.608070
7      1  2     var0  0.459626
8      2  2     var0  0.454319
9      0  0     var1  0.402119
10     1  0     var1  0.637941
11     2  0     var1  0.376392
12     0  1     var1  0.371620
13     1  1     var1  0.610397
14     2  1     var1  0.355516
15     0  2     var1  0.300022
16     1  2     var1  0.571157
17     2  2     var1  0.396294
18     0  0     var2  0.379483
19     1  0     var2  0.415869
20     2  0     var2  0.488103
21     0  1     var2  0.328365
22     1  1     var2  0.425340
23     2  1     var2  0.386236
24     0  2     var2  0.383425
25     1  2     var2  0.375043
26     2  2     var2  0.604078'
```

and plot with seaborn:

```
sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df4, col='cond', x='value', y='y', hue='variable')
```

[image]

Comment: I know already how to do this in pandas/numpy/whatever, I was just curious to understand whether seaborn can produce this plot with an ad-hoc function, since seaborn contains a lot of those